# need to add repositories path somewhere?

Tags: gitlab

Hello i'm having an issue where i need to add "repositories" to the git remote "add origin" command.
I'm running gitlab v5-4 on gentoo.

Did i miss a config setting somewhere ?
Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Here is some output.

```
wim@myserver ~/tmp $ git remote add origin git@myserver:tmp.git
wim@myserver ~/tmp $ git push -u origin master
Password:
fatal: 'tmp.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

however when i add repositories everything works fine:

```
wim@myserver ~/tmp $ git remote add origin git@myserver:repositories/tmp.git
wim@myserver ~/tmp $ git push -u origin master
Password:
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 206 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@myserver:repositories/tmp.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
```

some tests:

```
sudo -u git -H /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check
Check GitLab API access: OK
Check directories and files:
        /home/git/repositories: OK
        /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys: OK



sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
Checking Environment ...

Git configured for git user? ... yes
Has python2? ... yes
python2 is supported version? ... yes

Checking Environment ... Finished

Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version >= 1.4.0 ? ... OK (1.4.0)
Repo base directory exists? ... yes
Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no
Repo base owned by git:git? ... yes
Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
post-receive hook up-to-date? ... yes
post-receive hooks in repos are links: ...
tmp... ok

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... yes

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Database config exists? ... yes
Database is SQLite ... no
All migrations up? ... yes
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config outdated? ... no
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Init script exists? ... yes
Init script up-to-date? ... yes
Projects have satellites? ...
tmp... yes
Redis version >= 2.0.0? ... yes
Your git bin path is "/usr/bin/git"
Git version >= 1.7.10 ? ... yes (1.8.1)

Checking GitLab ... Finished
```

```
cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
command="/home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell key-2",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAAB3N etc...
```

repos path in gitlab-shell config.yml and gitlab.yml is set to "/home/git/repositories"

Comment: What's your repository path in `gitlab.yml` config file?

Comment: Additionally what's the repo path in `config.yml` of gitlab-shell?

Comment: its both set to "/home/git/repositories"

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you pass this?